# "from typing import List" vs "from ast import List"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In Python, if I use this:

```
from typing import List
```

I have to use `List[]`

---

If I use this:

```
from ast import List
```

I have to use `List()`

---

What is the difference?

Thanks.

googled "typing" and "ast" but no luck

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: The `ast` and the `typing` modules serve 2 completely, unrelated purposes. Sorry, but I highly doubt that *"googling 'typing' and 'ast'"* didn't at least lead you to [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#module-ast) and [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing)

Comment: If you use `from typing import List`, you *can* use `List` as a type hint; no one is making you.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that one is a type-hint; it describes a value, not holds elements itself. It is also optional.

The other is a runtime-class describing the Python syntax-tree, and holds a sequential collection of Python expressions. `ast.List` is required if you are building/using a parser.